# Powershell execute Queries using SQLPLUS

Tags: linux, bash, redhat, powershell, oracle

I have a RHEL server with Oracle 10G installed. I need to write a powershell script to query my database and get the output. I have imported Posh-SSH module and am able to connect to my RHEL server and execute commands using `Invoke-SSHCommand` however, i need help in executing sqlplus command using my `Invoke-SSHCommand`. Normally, we can achieve this in perl using EOF but, am not able to find any way to get this done using powershell.

**code for Perl using EOF:**

```
$command="export ORACLE_SID=database
sqlplus -S user/password<< EOF
set feedback off
select username from dba_users;
EOF"
```

**My Powershell code:**

```
$command="export ORACLE_SID=database
sqlplus -S user/password<< EOF
set feedback off
select username from dba_users;
EOF"

$result = Invoke-SSHCommand -Index 0 -Command $command
Write-Output $result
```

**My Output for Powershell:**

```
Host       : XX.XX.XXX.XXX
Output     : 
ExitStatus : 127
```

I guess, EOF characters are understood by Powershell.

Can anyone help me in converting this to powershell?. I've tried many ways but all in vain. Everytime i execute this code, I get Exit code: 127.

Answer (score 1):

That "EOF" string you're using up there on the Linux thing is not and character.  You're using a "here document". The EOF is just a string for perl to know where your here document ends. I always use something that is unlikely to be found IN the here document, like fInI.

Powershell. Yeah. Nightmare for us *nix folks.

Answer (score 1):

Im don't know too much about the Linux commands. 
You could try

```
$UserName = "username"
$Password = "password"
$tnsalias = "tnsalias"
$SqlQuery =
@'
set feedback off
select username from dba_users;
exit
'@

Invoke-SSHCommand -Command "$SqlQuery |
 sqlplus $username/$password@$tnsalias"
```